# Facebook Alers : Too Many Login Dialog Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have got this error message from facebook .

> Your app asks for 4+ read permissions along with public profile and
>   friend list. Asking for too many permissions can lower conversion by
>   as much as 40%. To improve your conversion rate and give people a
>   great app experience, we recommend that you ask for fewer permissions.
>   Read our règles élémentaires for more details.

My App ASK For This permissions :

> publish_stream, publish_actions, user_groups

So i dont know if i must ignore

> publish_stream

permission or not because my app just need to post contents no more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely ignore the `publish_stream` permission as it is already included with the `publish_actions` permission. Quoting from the [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/) about the same issue

> publish_actions will now include basic publish_stream permissions (including posting on a user's timeline, posting photos/videos, commenting on and liking content), which will appear on the first Auth Dialog screen. With this change, apps that were previously granted publish_stream do not need to request publish_actions.